# Homomorphic filtering on the frequency domain (Python & OpenCV)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, opencv

So, I need to build a homomorphic filter, but my code seems to be wrong. I don't know if it's execution or if it's some detail I don't know about in python, but I do know that it's wrong. I'd love som insights on what I can do to improve it.

I'm using

[image: this]

image as input reference, because it's on the Ricardo C. Gonzales book of DIP and I know how the output should look like. I'm even using the same parameters the book used in it's filter but it isn't working.

Gonzalez's Input and output, respectively:

[image: This is Gonzalez's input and output, respectively].

My output:

[image: This is my output using the same parameters]

My code is as follows:

```py
# coding: utf-8

import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

tss = cv2.imread("The_Seventh_Seal_1.jpg", 0)
mc = cv2.imread("mussels_cave_050.JPG", 0)
sh = cv2.imread("shelter_homomorphic.bmp", 0)
pet = cv2.imread("pet.png", 0)


def filtro_gaussiano_livro(img, gl, gh, inc, Dz):
    im = np.copy(img)
    P = im.shape[0] / 2
    Q = im.shape[1] / 2
    h = np.zeros(im.shape)
    U, V = np.meshgrid(range(im.shape[0]), range(im.shape[1]), sparse=False, indexing='ij')
    d = ((U - P) ** 2 + (V - Q) ** 2).astype(float)
    d0 = Dz
    c = inc
    h = (gh - gl) * (1 - (np.exp(-c * (d / (d0 ** 2))))) + gl
    return h


def filtro_gaussiano(img, Dz):
    im = np.copy(img)
    P = im.shape[0] / 2
    Q = im.shape[1] / 2
    h = np.zeros(im.shape)
    U, V = np.meshgrid(range(im.shape[0]), range(im.shape[1]), sparse=False, indexing='ij')
    d = (((U - P) ** 2) + ((V - Q) ** 2)).astype(float)
    h = 1 - np.exp(-(d / (2 * (Dz ** 2))))
    return h


def uint8_conv(img):
    mat = np.copy(img)
    for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
        for j in range(mat.shape[1]):
            if mat[i, j] < 0:
                mat[i, j] = 0
            elif mat[i, j] > 255:
                mat[i, j] = 255
            else:
                mat[i, j] = mat[i, j]
    return np.uint8(mat)


def reescalona(img, min, max):
    mat = np.copy(img)
    ph = cv2.add(min, (
        cv2.divide((cv2.multiply((cv2.subtract(mat, np.min(mat))), (max - min))), (np.max(mat) - np.min(mat)))))
    rtn = np.uint8(ph)
    return rtn


def homomorfica(img, l, s):
    im = np.float64(np.copy(img))
    cv2.imshow("BORDER", im)
    if s == 0:
        f = filtro_gaussiano(im, l)
    elif s == 1:
        f = filtro_gaussiano_livro(im, 0.05, 3.5, 1, l)
    cv2.imshow("gauss " + str(s), f)
    im_log = np.log1p(im)
    Im_shift = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(im_log))
    Im_fft_filt = np.multiply(f, Im_shift)
    cv2.imshow("FFT Shift", uint8_conv(np.real(Im_shift)))
    Im_filt = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(Im_fft_filt)))
    Im = np.exp(Im_filt) - 1
    Im = reescalona(Im, 0, 255)
    return uint8_conv(Im)


# def notch(img):



raio = 2500
i = pet
a = homomorfica(i, raio, 0)
b = homomorfica(i, raio, 1)
cv2.imshow("Imagem original", i)
cv2.imshow("Filtro homofobico comum", a)
cv2.imshow("Filtro homofobico do livro", b)

k = 0
while k != 27:
    k = cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Is the image you show your input or output. Please post your input, your output and the Gonzales output. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_filtering and https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2013/06/25/homomorphic-filtering-part-1/

Comment: @fmw42 updated it

Comment: I have tagged a duplicate post for segmenting license plate characters which provides an implementation of homomorphic filtering.  Have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do homomorphic filtering in the frequency domain using Python/Numpy/OpenCV.

I believe your issue is just your filtering.  I will show two different filters below that vary in radius of the circle and Gaussian filtering.

- Read the input as grayscale
- Take the natural log of the input
- Do FFT to real/imaginary components
- Shift the FFT so DC point is in the center
- Create a black circular mask on a white background of small radius
- Apply Gaussian blur to the mask
- Shift the FFT so DC point is at the top left corner
- Do IFFT and convert to a simple real image
- Take the exponential of the IFFT
- Stretch that to the range 0 to 255
- Save the result

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read input and convert to grayscale
img = cv2.imread('person.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# take ln of image
img_log = np.log(np.float64(img), dtype=np.float64)

# do dft saving as complex output
dft = np.fft.fft2(img_log, axes=(0,1))

# apply shift of origin to center of image
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)

# create black circle on white background for high pass filter
#radius = 3
radius = 13
mask = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float64)
cy = mask.shape[0] // 2
cx = mask.shape[1] // 2
cv2.circle(mask, (cx,cy), radius, 1, -1)
mask = 1 - mask

# antialias mask via blurring
#mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (7,7), 0)
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (47,47), 0)

# apply mask to dft_shift
dft_shift_filtered = np.multiply(dft_shift,mask)

# shift origin from center to upper left corner
back_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(dft_shift_filtered)

# do idft saving as complex
img_back = np.fft.ifft2(back_ishift, axes=(0,1))

# combine complex real and imaginary components to form (the magnitude for) the original image again
img_back = np.abs(img_back)

# apply exp to reverse the earlier log
img_homomorphic = np.exp(img_back, dtype=np.float64)

# scale result
img_homomorphic = cv2.normalize(img_homomorphic, None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("person_dft_numpy_mask.png", (255*mask).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite("person_dft_numpy_homomorphic.png", img_homomorphic)

cv2.imshow("ORIGINAL", img)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("FILTERED DFT/IFT ROUND TRIP", img_back)
cv2.imshow("HOMOMORPHIC", img_homomorphic)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

High Pass Filter Mask and Homomorphic Result for radius=3 and blur=7:

[image]

[image]

High Pass Filter Mask and Homomorphic Result for radius=13 and blur=47:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was using the parameters given by the book, but I forgot to edit them in when I posted.
GammaL = 0.25, GammaH = 2 and D0 = 80.
I'm trying to replicate the results using the same parameters to see if my result is right

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the book to know what they did.

Comment: np man, thanks for the answer! I left out important information, so it's on me

Comment: What is the equation for the high pass filter? Which equation number from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/284015115_Mathematical_Equations_for_Homomorphic_Filtering_in_Frequency_Domain_A_Literature_Survey

Comment: equation number 8 is the one, sry, I answered it yesterdey but it didn't register, for some reason

Comment: I have another solution using that equation, but I cannot post it since the question has been closed. If you post your email address in your profile, then I can mail it to you. I have to modify the arguments you gave to gl = 0.25; gh = 2; d0 = 8; c = 0.05. Then at the end I stretch the result using cv2.normalize(img_homomorphic, None, alpha=-32, beta=756, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U). I also normalized the image to float in the range 0 to 1 before the log and scaled back to range 0 to 255 as uint8 after the exp. That avoids the issue of log(0).